# Delphi FMX and Android GO

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Has anyone experience with "Android GO" custom UI running a delphi FMX application? Is the .apk produced by delphi compatible?

There are several tablets (eg Lenovo 7" with Android Oreo) with a lightweight custom UI on top called Android Go and I am wondering if this could lead to compatibility issues with my app that is already working on android devices.)

https://www.android.com/versions/go-edition/

Comment: 10 seconds of Googling later: https://developer.android.com/google-play/guides/android-go-edition

Comment: thanx Dave but that is already known. as you can read in my question, i am seeking for delphi programmers with actual experience on the matter. the android developer page describes interesting facts as in theory yet we do know in reality many, many things in the fmx platform may conflict in the most funny - and disturbing - ways with the host operating system.

Answer (score 1):

We tested various FMX Android apps on a Samsung Galaxy J2 Core, maybe one of the most basic phones out there running Android Go and we have observed no compatibility problems so far. Note that Android Go doesn't necessarily sacrifices OS features, but devices running it may aggressively optimize memory and storage usage.

Anyway you may want to adhere to the [Android Go guidelines](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/build-for-billions/device-capacity#androidgo) to ensure a good experience for users.